# How to turn off autosignin of registered transports in Openfire?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

This is regarding the gateway XEP 0100 support in Openfire.

I have noticed that for some transports, they are auto-signed in once a connection to openfire succeeds (via the xmpp user). This applies specifically to QQ. How does one turn off this auto-signin feature ? Basically from a client perspective, I want to be able to signin selectively. So when I create an XMPPConnection to openfire, all transports should remain signed off until I send directed Presences to transports.

Answer (score 0):

Which transports do and which ones don't?  Start by looking at the XMPP data sent from the client.  See what each packet to the transports is doing.  Once you've eliminated client packet differences you can look at each transport configuration.  Are these native transports to openfire, or are these third party transports you've hooked in?